# Chop off the first letter of every variable name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some data that looks like this:

```
    country agdp apop
1        US  100  100
2 Australia   50   50
```

The variable names are `agdp` and `apop`, but I would like them to be `gdp` and `pop`. My real data has many, many variables that all need that transformation.

And this is what my desired outcome:

```
 country gdp pop
1        US  100  100
2 Australia   50   50
```

Reproducible code below:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     country = c("US", "Australia"),
        agdp = c(100, 50),
        apop = c(100, 50)

desired_df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     country = c("US", "Australia"),
        gdp = c(100, 50),
        pop = c(100, 50)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/35113553/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954165/rename-a-set-of-columns-in-r-by-position

Answer (score 4):

Using `regex` we can extract everything other than first character and assign the names.

```
names(df)[-1] <- sub("^.(.*)$", "\\1", names(df)[-1])

df
#    country gdp pop
#1        US 100 100
#2 Australia  50  50
```

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rename_at(2:length(.), list(~ substr(., 2, nchar(.))))

    country gdp pop
1        US 100 100
2 Australia  50  50
```

The same with `base R`:

```
names(df)[-1] <- substr(names(df)[-1], 2, nchar(names(df)[-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach

```
library(stringr)

names(df)[-1] = str_sub(names(df)[-1], 2)
```

Comment: Adding to this, you could swap out `str_sub` with `substring` if you wanted to use a base function.

Answer (score 1):

One could also do:

Purely `base`(can use `setdiff` or `%in%` to "automate" selection.):

```
sapply(names(df), function(x) ifelse(x=="country",x,substring(x,2,nchar(x))))
```

Less elegant with `tidyverse` since `rename_at` has been shown:

```
names(df)<-unlist(names(df) %>% 
  map(.,function(x) ifelse(x=="country",x,substring(x,2,nchar(x)))))
```